# Why does await work on multiple lines but not in one line?

Tags: c#, async-await, syntax

I can get the following logic to work in 2 lines, but cannot pull it off inline:

```
var result = await BuildNewsCategories();
x.ListBuilder = () => result.Select(x => _mapper.Map<a, b>(x)).ToList();
```

My first attempt simply warns to add async:

```
x.ListBuilder = async () => await BuildNewsCategories()
   .Select(x => _mapper.Map<a, b>(x)).ToList();
```

But this is where I get stuck as now `.Select` is not found.

Comment: Add parentheses: `(await BuildNewsCategories())`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should postfix all methods that are `async` with the word "Async". If `BuildNewsCategories` is in fact async, it should be named `BuildNewsCategoriesAsync` for clarity.

Comment: What is the type of the `ListBuilder` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.ListBuilder` is a synchronous delegate, so you cannot change this to a one-liner.

Not without blocking anyway which should be avoided.

---

Even if you were to block, for example:

```
x.ListBuilder = () => BuildNewsCategories()
   .Result
   .Select(_mapper.Map<a, b>)
   .ToList();
```

This would change the semantics of your code, because now `BuildNewsCategories()` is evaluated *each time* the delegate is invoked.

Comment: is there anything tricky I can do with Task.Run and/or an anonymous function.  Because of how our caching works anything outside of that 1 line is more expensive.

Comment: Without knowing the wider context I can't advise further. Based on the code you have shared, and assuming `BuildNewsCategories` has a truly asynchronous implementation, your first example is the optimal solution.

Comment: It could also cause deadlocks, depending on where this code is used

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: **No, you cannot turn this into a usable one-liner since you have a synchronous delegate**.

The rest of this answer provides extra information & potential solutions for other problems which may come up for when searching for this question.

---

Not having parentheses around `await BuildNewsCategories()` means that the compiler has no way of knowing:

- Are you trying to do `.Select` on the `Task<TResult`?
  Or:
- Are you trying to do `.Select` on the result of the `Task` (`TResult`)?

Without parentheses, it thinks you're attempting to call the LINQ `.Select` extension method on the `Task` returned & not the actual returned result (the "unwrapped" `await`ed result).

To do `.Select` on the result of the `Task`, surround `await BuildNewsCategories()` in parentheses:

---

If `x.ListBuilder` is of type `List<T>`:

```
x.ListBuilder = (await BuildNewsCategories())
                .Select(x => _mapper.Map<a, b>(x))
                .ToList()
```

---

If `x.ListBuilder` is of type `Func<Task<List<T>>>`:

```
x.ListBuilder = async () => (await BuildNewsCategories())
                            .Select(x => _mapper.Map<a, b>(x))
                            .ToList();
```

---

If `x.ListBuilder` is of type `Func<List<T>>`, your delegate is synchronous & you won't be able to get a one-liner without blocking on asynchronous code (defeating the purpose).

Your original solution would be the answer in this case:

```
var result = await BuildNewsCategories();
x.ListBuilder = () => result
                      .Select(x => _mapper.Map<a, b>(x))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Where does the `async` go?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The `async` is unnecessary. The problem is that `BuildNewsCategories()` appears to be an `async` method, but OP is not actually awaiting the result of the Task, so their code is attempting to invoke LINQ's Select on the Task itself, not the result.

Comment: Ah,  I see. (15 char minimum).

Comment: @RobertHarvey the `async` goes on the definition of `BuildNewsCategories()`

Comment: This is mostly correct, though I'd prefer to see an explanation as to *why* the parentheses are needed.

Comment: But ListBuilder seems to be a delegate (or Action) type in the question, not a List.

Comment: @KlausGütter ultimately I think that first snippet is irrelevant to the question of "why isn't this code working?"

Comment: `x.ListBuilder` is a delegate type. Look at the first example which compiles.

Comment: I tried to wrap it also, but then it gets confused..  The error appears under the arrow, saying that it cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type Func<List<b>>

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Still wrong. `x.ListBuilder` is a synchronous delegate.

Comment: Your code won't work, you cannot use `await` inside a non-async lambda

Comment: With every edit you make your answer worse. The real answer is that you cannot do it on a single line, well unless you do `BuildNewsCategories().GetAwaiter().GetResult()....` but that is horrible and should be avoided.

Comment: The only real answer is: it cannot be done. The code posted in the question demonstrates that `ListBuilder` is a synchronous delegate and hence `await` cannot be used, which makes most of this answer irrelevant. I don't know how this got so many upvotes

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The final section of the answer highlights this however there are also other aspects to the answer, which may help other with similar problems - I have mentioned that the original solution is the only way in this case. I would say to genuinely feel free to add in an answer which you may feel like answers this better & I’ll upvote.

Answer (score -2):

The other answers get the issue with the parentheses right, but do not return a delegate, but a list.

So this would be the correct code:

```
x.ListBuilder = async () => (await BuildNewsCategories())
             .Select(x => _mapper.Map<a, b>(x)).ToList();
```

This will work, if `x.ListBuilder` is of type `Func<Task<List<b>>>`, so it can be called as `var list = await x.ListBuilder()`. If it must be  `Func<List<b>>`, it cannot be called asynchrounously and you have to move the `await BuildNewsCategories()` in a separate statement (your first snippet).

Comment: I tried to wrap it also, but then it gets confused.. The error appears under the arrow, saying that it cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type Func<List<b>>

Comment: @JBoothUA Can you change ListBuilder to Func<Task<List<b>>>? If not, then you must stick to your two-line solution.

Comment: @JBoothUA `Func<List<b>>` is a synchronous delegate, so you can't convert your code to a one-liner.